# How do I install zopectl?

Tags: command-line

while trying to install zopectl and zope testcase I am getting this error:

```
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~/zopectl$ sudo apt-get install zopectl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zopectl
```

I put the tar file in my home directory.  But  I don't know why I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

With many applications, there are multiple ways to download/install them.  One way is through `apt-get` and another is by downloading and untaring the .tar file.  Note, that `apt-get` has **nothing** to do with the .tar file.

```
Unable to locate package zopectl
```

Typically, that error indicates the package you are trying to install cannot be found in any of your defined repositories.  Have you done a `sudo apt-get update`?  Run that command and then try again.

If you cannot get the `apt-get install` to work, you should be able to install this application by untar-ing the .tar file (which you say you have already downloaded).  In terminal, change to your home directory (`cd ~`) and try this:

```
tar -xvf nameOfTarFile.tar
```

Note that if the file you downloaded is a tar.gz file, you'll need to set one more flag to get that to work:

```
tar -zxvf nameOfTarFile.tar
```

Comment: now i m getting error like this----------------------------------------------E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: For that problem, we've got a whole slew of answers.  Check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem